# ASP.Net Health Monitoring - How to check Requests Queued

Tags: .net, asp.net, instrumentation, health-monitoring

I have just discovered ASP.Net Health Monitoring - it looks awesome. I have been developing ASP.Net apps for years, and have even taken the Microsoft certs and have never seen it before. I can't believe it is so hidden. It must be one of the best kept secrets of .Net... anyway, I digress. Here is my question:

I would like to use ASP.Net Health Monitoring to do the following (below). I am having trouble working out exactly how I would achieve this.  Any advice appreciated!

**Goal 1:**

- Receive an email once a day
- Email to contain a list of the number requests that were queued at 5 minute intervals throughout the day

E.G: I would like to receive an email like the following

~~Daily Request Queue Summary~~

- 0:00 am - 2
- 0:05 am - 10
- 0:10 am - 7
- ...

**Goal 2:**
I would like to receive a warning email if the number of queued requests goes over X amount

---

### ~Update~

I know I can create a custom event.  I also know that I can get the queued requests using the WebProcessStatistics class.  Here are the things I am now struggling with

- How can I get this event to fire every X many minuets?  Can the WebHeartBeat event be used for this? I don't really understand how the WebHeartBeat event can be used
- How can I get this information to go into a daily email? Is it just a question of setting up 24 hour buffering, or is there a better way?

Thanks

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: any sample code, please ? how do implement the custom event ?? it will be clearly to find solution –

Comment: So? Did you find out how to do it ?

Comment: There's a reason it's not so popular. Reporting isn't easy with HM. See http://mvolo.com/asp-net-health-monitoring-8-years-later/